# ¿Cómo puedo crear una lista a partir de un array?

Tags: php, array

Quiero crear un lista "menú" como la siguiente a partir de un array:

- Primer Area

  - subMenu1
  - subMenu2
- Segunda Area

  - subMenu1
  - subMenu2
  - subMenu3
- Tercer Area

  - subMenu1
  - subMenu2
  - subMenu3
  - subMenu4
- Cuarta Area

  - subMenu1
  - subMenu2
  - subMenu3
  - subMenu4
  - subMenu5

y así dependiendo de x datos que contenga el array el cual tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
$datos= [
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data1', 'nombre'=>'Datos1', 'area'=>'Admin'],
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data1', 'nombre'=>'Datos2', 'area'=>'Admin'],
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data1', 'nombre'=>'Datos3', 'area'=>'Admin'],
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data2', 'nombre'=>'Datos4', 'area'=>'Soporte'],
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data2', 'nombre'=>'Datos5', 'area'=>'Soporte'],
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data3', 'nombre'=>'Datos6', 'area'=>'Catalogos'],
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data3', 'nombre'=>'Datos7', 'area'=>'Catalogos'],
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data3', 'nombre'=>'Datos8', 'area'=>'Catalogos'],
    ['ruta'=>'/modulos/data3', 'nombre'=>'Datos9', 'area'=>'Catalogos']];
```

intenté con el siguiente for pero solo pone uno por área:

algo así:

- area 1

  - *subMenu1
- area 2

  - *subMenu1

_______________FOR____________________

```
$nombre="";
$area="";
for($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++){
    if($datos[$i]['area'] != $area || $area = "" ){
        $nombre .= '<li class="active treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>'.$datos[$i]['area'].'</span>
                            <span class="pull-right-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">';

                    $nombre .= "<li><a href='".$datos[$i]['ruta']."'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> ".$datos[$i]['nombre']."</a></li>";
                    if($datos[$i]['area'] != $area) {
                        $nombre .= "</ul></li>";
                    }

                }else if($datos[$i]['area'] == $area){
                    $nombre .= "<li><a href='".$datos[$i]['ruta']."'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i> ".$datos[$i]['nombre']."</a></li>";
                    if($datos[$i]['area'] != $area) {
                        $nombre .= "</ul></li>";
                    }

                }
                $area = $datos[$i]['area'];
            }
```

Ejemplo del contenido de print_r($datos):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [nombre] => Selección 
        [ruta] => modulos/admin/usuarios 
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [nombre] => Hornos 
        [ruta] => modulos/hornos/produccion 
    ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [nombre] => Hornos 
        [ruta] => modulos/hornos/tiemposMuertos 
    ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [nombre] => Todas 
        [ruta] => modulos/admin/permisos 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: ¿Y el array cuál es? Lo de `PrimeraArea`... `subMenu`...  no lo veo en la variable `$permisos`. Comparte el array que quieres leer que imagino será `$datos`;

Comment: perdón , el array que quiero leer es $datos es el que contiene lo que se necesita para crear el menu

Comment: Yaaa, pero comparte lo que hay en `$datos`, el código donde lo creas o el resultado de un `print_r($datos);`

Comment: @A.Cedano puse el print_r($datos); al final con lo que tiene ahorita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto resolverá tu problema, si los datos están como los muestras en el array.

#### Código:

#### <kbd>[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/SOOI26290)</kbd>

```
<?php 

$datos= [
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data1', 'nombre'=>'Datos1', 'area'=>'Admin'],
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data1', 'nombre'=>'Datos2', 'area'=>'Admin'],
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data1', 'nombre'=>'Datos3', 'area'=>'Admin'],
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data2', 'nombre'=>'Datos4', 'area'=>'Soporte'],
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data2', 'nombre'=>'Datos5', 'area'=>'Soporte'],
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data3', 'nombre'=>'Datos6', 'area'=>'Catalogos'],
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data3', 'nombre'=>'Datos7', 'area'=>'Catalogos'],
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data3', 'nombre'=>'Datos8', 'area'=>'Catalogos'],
['ruta'=>'/modulos/data3', 'nombre'=>'Datos9', 'area'=>'Catalogos']];

$excluir = ['ruta' => FALSE, 'nombre' => FALSE];
foreach($datos as $v) 
{
    $grupos = $v['area'];
    $registro = array_diff_key( $v, $excluir );
    if ( ! isset($arrResultado[$grupos] ) ) 
    {
        $arrResultado[$grupos]['opciones'] = [];
    }

    $arrOpciones = array_diff_key( $v, $registro );
    $arrResultado[$grupos]['opciones'][] = $arrOpciones;
}


$strHTML="<ul>";
foreach ($arrResultado as $k=>$v)
{
    $strHTML.="<li>$k</li><ul>";

    foreach ($v["opciones"] as $opcion)
    {
        $strHTML.="<li>".$opcion["nombre"]." - ".$opcion["ruta"]."</li>";
    }

    $strHTML.="</ul>";

}

$strHTML.="</ul>";
echo $strHTML;    
?>
```

---

#### Resultado:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Admin</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Datos1 - /modulos/data1</li>
    <li>Datos2 - /modulos/data1</li>
    <li>Datos3 - /modulos/data1</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Soporte</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Datos4 - /modulos/data2</li>
    <li>Datos5 - /modulos/data2</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Catalogos</li>
  <ul>
    <li>Datos6 - /modulos/data3</li>
    <li>Datos7 - /modulos/data3</li>
    <li>Datos8 - /modulos/data3</li>
    <li>Datos9 - /modulos/data3</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```